# How to add Muliple Custom Icons to Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my first time with flutter and I started adding custom icons. I did this by uploading svg-files to https://www.fluttericon.com/ and converting them to `.ttf`-files.

Now I have three custom Icons, so I made 3 `.ttf`-files, and I tried implementing them as following:

`pubspec.yaml`:

```
flutter:
  generate: true

  fonts:

    - family:  BikeIcon
      fonts:
        - asset: ./assets/fonts/icons/Bike.ttf

    - family:  LocationIcon
      fonts:
        - asset: ./assets/fonts/icons/Location.ttf
```

`custom_icons.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class CustomIcons {
  CustomIcons._();

  static const String? _kFontPkg = null;

  static const IconData bike_icon =
      IconData(0xe800, fontFamily: 'BikeIcon', fontPackage: _kFontPkg);

  static const IconData location_icon =
      IconData(0xe800, fontFamily: 'LocationIcon', fontPackage: _kFontPkg);
}
```

The first icon `bike_icon`works perfectly. The second doesn't get displayed, so its just empty, even though the `.ttf` is valid, I checked it...

Did I miss something or missunderstood how this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

Just as said in previous answers of this question, the problem was the codePoint. When generating `.ttf` files from https://www.fluttericon.com/, there is a dart file in which the right implementation is shown, including the codePoint. All I had to do is copying the code point for each icon and add it to my `custom_icons.dart` file

Thanks for the help :)